# Using + (Plus) instead of %20 in html form submit

Tags: url, get, ascii, form-submit, urlencode

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/example.com/search" method="get" id="frm_Search">
<input type="text" name="search_text" placeholder=" Keyword...">                   
</form>
```

When form is submited with example keyword "space cat", my landing page becomes following url:

> /example.com/search/?search_text=space%20cat

But I want it to be `space+cat`, not `space%20cat`